# Как можно сделать прямую трансляцию своего сайта на Ютуб?

Tags: веб-программирование, youtube, streaming, online-video, веб-сайт

Нужно реализовать прямую трансляцию сайта со статистикой на Ютуб. Сам сайт лежит на Linux сервере. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным. На Ютубе много подобных трансляций, по типу статистики заболевания ковидом и т.д.

Comment: OBS? Либо рендеринг картинки из Headless-chrome и стримминг через ffmpeg

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.